# App crashes everytime on moving from activity, with no errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently facing a problem on an app I'm developing that simply can't debug. I'm on SDK 27, Graddle 3.0.1, using ZXing 1.9.8.

In an Activity, I call for a QR Reader class I made out of ZXing library, so it reads the code and sends it to another Activity via Bundle for it to analyse it.

What is happening is it opens the camera, reads the code, then the app closes, out of nowhere, doesn't even get to open the next Activity.
When the user chooses to insert the code by hand on a little input dialog I made, it now reaches the next activity, but it's simply too unpredictable since it doesn't stop on any breakpoint there so I can debug it.

I reduced the amount of errors by putting Sleeps of 1sec between calling ***bundle.putExtra*** and ***startactivity()*** which is as understandable to me as black magic.

Since there are no errors, I started looking at the logcat and found this, repeatedly:

```
01-29 15:28:32.706 701-765/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.psa.dkd/.activities.GetCarDetails: +90ms
01-29 15:28:32.858 701-1562/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{f7887c u0 com.psa.dkd/com.psa.dkd.activities.GetCarDetails}
01-29 15:28:32.862 701-889/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{7d4750 u0 com.psa.dkd/.activities.GetCarDetails t165}: app died, no saved state
01-29 15:28:32.869 701-1530/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{6bb4c7f u0 com.psa.dkd/com.psa.dkd.activities.ReaderQR EXITING}
01-29 15:28:32.871 701-1486/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{11094d u0 SurfaceView - com.psa.dkd/com.psa.dkd.activities.ReaderQR EXITING}
01-29 15:28:32.875 701-1528/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{a96ce5a u0 com.psa.dkd/com.psa.dkd.activities.ReadChassisActivity}
```

From what I gathered, WIN DEATH happens when the main thread has too much work to execute, but this had worked in the past, perfectly. Besides, there isn't that much work in the main thread since I use threads when possible.

Could it have been an update that caused this? I'm lost.

***EDIT***

ReadChassisActivity: https://pastebin.com/r60SPPHF

ReaderQR: https://pastebin.com/PSPT29Da

GetCarDetails: https://pastebin.com/Sgbi1XDi

ReadChassisActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.psa.dkd.R;
import com.psa.dkd.utils.Logger;
import com.psa.dkd.utils.SessionManagement;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ReadChassisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int BARCODE_READER_REQUEST_CODE;
    SessionManagement session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_chassis);
        session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());

        setTitle("Welcome" + session.getUserDetails().get("name"));

        RelativeLayout new_car_manual = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.new_car_manual);
        new_car_manual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ReadChassisActivity.this);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.input_prompt, null);
                final EditText input = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
                input.requestFocus();

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReadChassisActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Manual Input");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Insert barcode");
                alertDialog.setView(promptsView);
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String result = input.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
                        Logger.writeToLog(result, 0, 9);
                        Logger.writeLogToDB(session, 0, result, 9, 0);
                        Intent workIntent = new Intent(ReadChassisActivity.this, GetCarDetails.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("car_code", result);
                        workIntent.putExtras(b);
                        /*try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }*/
                        startActivity(workIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        RelativeLayout new_car = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.new_car);
        new_car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(ReadChassisActivity.this, "Connecting camera...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ReadChassisActivity.this, ReaderQR.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, BARCODE_READER_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        RelativeLayout exit = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReadChassisActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Exit");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Return to login");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finishAffinity();
                        finish();
                        //session.logoutUser();
                        Intent i = new Intent(ReadChassisActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == BARCODE_READER_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String result = data.getStringExtra("code");
                Logger.writeToLog(result, 0, 9);
                Logger.writeLogToDB(session, 0, result, 9, 0);

                Intent workIntent = new Intent(ReadChassisActivity.this, GetCarDetails.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("car_code", result);
                workIntent.putExtras(b);
                /*try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/
                startActivity(workIntent);
                finish();
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No results", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent choiceIntent = new Intent(ReadChassisActivity.this, ReadChassisActivity.class);
                startActivity(choiceIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
}
```

ReaderQR

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.psa.dkd.R;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ReaderQR extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader_qr);
        QrScanner(this.mScannerView);
        setTitle("Pass it over the code!");
    }

    public void QrScanner(View view) {
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("code", rawResult.getText());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

GetCarDetails

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.psa.dkd.R;
import com.psa.dkd.utils.SessionManagement;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import static com.psa.dkd.utils.Misc.jsonToMap;

public class GetCarDetails extends Activity {

    private final int WAIT_TIME = 1000;
    private String car_code;
    private String server;
    private String worker_id;
    private HashMap<String, String> car_data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_details);
        findViewById(R.id.mainSpinner2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(GetCarDetails.this);
        this.server = session.getUserDetails().get("server");
        this.worker_id = session.getUserDetails().get("id");
        this.car_code = getIntent().getExtras().getString("car_code");

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // GET CAR DETAILS FROM DB - car_code

                try {
                        Log.d("TEST", "TRYING...");
                    String result = new getCarData().execute("APP/getCarDetails.php", car_code, worker_id).get();
                    Log.d("TEST", "RECEIVED: " + result);
                    car_data = jsonToMap(result);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | JSON    Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TESTE", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error has happened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent choiceIntent = new Intent(GetCarDetails.this, ReadChassisActivity.class);
                    startActivity(choiceIntent);
                    finish();
                }

                if (car_data.get("result").equals("1")) {
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("car_code", car_code);
                    (...)
                    Intent i = new Intent(GetCarDetails.this, JobSelectActivity.class);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    if (car_data.get("result").equals("0")) {
                        Toast.makeText(GetCarDetails.this, "Nothing scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(GetCarDetails.this, "This one is done, take another", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(GetCarDetails.this, ReadChassisActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }, WAIT_TIME);
    }

    public class getCarData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String text = "";
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(server + params[0]);
                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                postDataParams.put("code", params[1]);
                postDataParams.put("user_id", params[1]);

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000); // milliseconds
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000); // milliseconds
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("json", postDataParams.toString());

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                String param = "json=" + URLEncoder.encode(postDataParams.toString(), "UTF-8");
                wr.write(param.getBytes());
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                // Get the server response
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                // Read Server Response
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Append server response in string
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                text = sb.toString();
                return text;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ERROR FETCHING DATA", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put your code to let people help and understand better..

Comment: @AalapPatel Added pastebin links. Thank you for your time

Comment: we don't want pastebin links, we want code

Comment: @TimCastelijns I was just trying to be practical, sorry,  added the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove Toast.makeText

I've been searching similar bug for the last 3 days. I had no exception, only WINDEATH like you.

I hope it could be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to resume the camera handler after you've received the camera result. You need to add the following:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}
```

Look at the sample: https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/zxing-sample/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/sample/SimpleScannerActivity.java

Comment: Same results. The app is killed right after getting a result. Thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

So, I kept trying out other methods, I came to this:

```
(...)
Intent workIntent = new Intent(ReadChassisActivity.this, GetCarDetails.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("car_code", result);
workIntent.putExtras(b);
try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
startActivity(workIntent);
finish();
```

Seems like giving time for the putExtras() method to execute solves the issue, with minimal impact on usability.

Why is this? Besides, this looks like using duct tape to hold a building to me, isn't there a better way?